# What is this meaning of this terenary operation?

Tags: java, c, operators, conditional-statements, ternary

Please refer to the following method:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

I always thought the first part of a Ternary operator must be a condition, but here it's a return statement instead and I'm confused.

Comment: The return keyword merely says "return the value of the following expression". Now, can you understand the expression that follows?

Answer (score 3):

Read it like this

```
return (b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE);
```

does it make more sense now? You're just deciding what to return, depending on the value of your condition `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Its equivalent to :

```
if(b)
return Boolean.TRUE 
else
return Boolean.FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

(boolean) `b` is a **condition**. What do You expect? **Expression** isn't required

Answer (score 1):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) suggest the following explanation:

> In computer science, a ternary operator (sometimes incorrectly called a tertiary operator) is an operator that takes three arguments. The arguments and result can be of different types. Many programming languages that use C-like syntax feature a ternary operator, ?: , which defines a conditional expression.

And not only in Java, this syntax is available within PHP too.

In the following [link](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/T/ternary_operator.html) it gives the following explanation, which is quiet good to understand it:

> A ternary operator is some operation operating on 3 inputs. It's a shortcut for an if-else statement, and is also known as a conditional operator.
>
> **In Perl/PHP it works as:**
>  `boolean_condition?true_value:false_value`
>
> **In C/C++ it works as:**
> `logical expression? action for true : action for false`

This might be readable for some logical conditions which are not too complex otherwise it is better to use If-Else block with intended combination of conditional logic.

We can simplify the If-Else blocks with this Ternary operator for one code statement line. For Example:

```
if ( car.isStarted() ) {
     car.goForward();
} else {
     car.startTheEngine();
}
```

Might be equal to the following:

```
( car.isStarted() ) ? car.goForward() : car.startTheEngine();
```

So if we refer to your method:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    return b ? Boolean.TRUE : Boolean.FALSE;
}
```

It is actually the 100% equivalent of the following:

```
public static Boolean valueOf(boolean b) {
    if (b == Boolean.TRUE) {
        return Boolean.TRUE;
    } else {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

That's it! 
Hope this was helpful to somebody!
Cheers!